# MySQL output in PHP tables

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am currently designing a product selection page.

I wanna show my users a series of products that I have in my SQL table.

I want to output my SQL into php tables, but I dont want one long table.

I need one table per product.

In short terms,

Product 1, in one table

Break

Product 2, in other table.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","headsets");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `modeller");
echo "<table border='1'>";
$i = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    if ($i == 0) {
      $i++;
      echo "<tr>";
      foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        echo "<th>" . $key . "</th>";
      }
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $value) {
      echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The sql part works fine, its just the way php output it I want to change

[krasipenkovs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI3Ft.png)

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpghJ.png)

Comment: You say the SQL part is fine, but `"SELECT * FROM \`modeller"` won't work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include your code directly (and well-formatted) in your question.

Comment: You have quote before `modeller`

Comment: We'd need to see your mysql structure table structure, and example data

Comment: @JonStirling It does work that way.

Comment: Given what you posted, I find that rather hard to believe.

Comment: You were right, Typo! but can you help me with my tables thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","headsets");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `modeller`");

$i = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    //if ($i == 0) {
      //$i++;
      //echo "<tr>";
      //foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        //echo "<th>" . $key . "</th>";
      //}
      //echo "</tr>";
    //}
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $value) {
      echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "</table><br />";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: One table for each row?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Exactly i need one table for each row. Above answer does not work.

Comment: Yes that is what is asked for in the question

Comment: and if you add `<br />` tag after the closing `</table>`?

Comment: @krasipenkov after i try this, the table looks like its been sliced into 50 parts.

Comment: add a screenshot otherwise would be a guess for us

Comment: @krasipenkov ive added screshots to post

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Do you want every table to have header with column names or just the first one?

Comment: @krasipenkov can you remove the headers from all tables ?

Comment: Now only the first table has header row with column names. The rest have only data row.

Comment: @krasipenkov Is it possible to remove headings from first table also ?

Comment: I just commented out the code for the header in first table.

Comment: Thank you very much! ive marked your answer as resolution

Comment: I hope it helped.